# Hibernate Envers - Audit Tables are not getting created

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have below setting in hibernate properties file

```
hibernate.ddl-auto=update
org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix=_AUDITED
```

And in pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have annotated my entity class with @Audited. Hibernate version is 5.1.0.Final

What I am I doing wrong? My Audited tables are not getting created. I get the below exception when envers tries to insert in Audit table.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute batch; SQL [insert into dbo.STPTradeTicket_AUDITED (REVTYPE, DownStreamTicketId, TicketId, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute batch
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.barclays.ib.syndicate.booking.service.impl.TradeTicketService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4a814103.open(<generated>)
    at com.barclays.ib.syndicate.booking.service.engine.TradeGenerator.run(TradeGenerator.java:118)
    at com.barclays.ib.syndicate.booking.service.engine.TradeEngineThreadPool$TradeEngineThreadPoolThread.run(TradeEngineThreadPool.java:71)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.getBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2901)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3421)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2353)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Invalid object name 'dbo.STPTradeTicket_AUDITED'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The property `hibernate.ddl-auto=update` isn't correct.  You mention setting this in your *hibernate* properties file so I'm going to assume what you want to use is the following:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

If you are using Spring's configuration to specify the value, then you would use

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

As you can see, the declaration of the property name is more different than most.